# How resolve cannot read property "classList" in unit testing with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, enzyme

i have write a function in my react component as shown below.

```
 myFunction(){
if (this.state.isTrue) {
  document.querySelector(".myClass").classList.remove('class-false');
} else {
  document.querySelector(".myClass").classList.add('class-true');
}
```

}

but in my test case when i simulate click it is throwing error like "cannot read property classList" as shown below

[image]

Comment: `document.querySelector(".myClass")` is returning `null`, which doesn't have `classList` property. Likely there isn't any elements with `myClass` class. You could do something like `document.querySelector(".myClass") ? document.querySelector(".myClass").classList.remove('class-false') : ''`

Comment: yeah i k now that. what i want is, i am mocking a different component and changing class value in another component

Comment: when i do enzymeWrapper.find('myclass').simulate('click'); in component one its throwing error, since .myclass is not available